# Jenkins CI + Grails 2.3.9 Setup, Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure

Tags: grails, jenkins, continuous-integration

I followed [this tutorial](http://acataleptii.blogspot.com/2014/07/setting-up-jenkins-on-ubuntu-1404.html) on how to setup Jenkins on Ubuntu! I was able to set it up with no problem at all. I was even able to hook it up with git lab so that everytime I push, jenkins starts a build. However, I have not had success in figuring out how to do a test-app or even a simple grails clean on it. The stacktrace doesn't have a clear cut explanation why it failed. I have installed grails, and java and had it setup on `jenkins>manage jenkins>configure system`

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.com:xyza/test.git
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.com:xyza/test.git
 > git --version
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.com:xyza/test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse origin/develop^{commit}
Checking out Revision c76d153311fe24a9f282e3ec4ac33f73cb600420 (origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout
 > git checkout -f c76d153311fe24a9f282e3ec4ac33f73cb600420
 > git rev-list c76d153311fe24a9f282e3ec4ac33f73cb600420
[workspace] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstallation/Grails_2.3.9/bin/grails -Dgrails.work.dir=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace//target clean --non-interactive --plain-output
|Loading Grails 2.3.9
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

My current setup looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/472qo.png. Any help would be appreciated. :)

EDIT:

As someone suggested, I tried running the app manually using the command that jenkins generated, but I get this error instead:

```
user@shiva:~$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstallation/Grails_2.3.9/bin/grails -Dgrails.work.dir=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace//target clean --non-interactive --plain-output
|Loading Grails 2.3.9
|Configuring classpath
Error |
/var/lib/jenkins does not appear to be part of a Grails application.
Error |
The following commands are supported outside of a project:
    add-proxy
    clear-proxy
    create-app
    create-multi-project-build
    create-plugin
    help
    install-app-templates
    list-plugins
    package-plugin
    plugin-info
    remove-proxy
    set-proxy
|Run 'grails help' for a complete list of available scripts.
```

Comment: Did you try to run Grails in the bash without jenkins? Please go to the dir `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace` and try. Maybe Grails will say you something important.

Comment: What version of Jenkins and the Grails plugin to Jenkins are you using?

Comment: @wwarlock I tried running the command, see my stacktrace above.

Comment: @Joe I am using Jenkins ver. 1.570 and plugin version is 1.7

Comment: Alright, I looked around Jira and it seems to be breaking for a lot of people.. I guess I'll have to wait until an update comes in..